# Android app - Check if user's current location equal to a (String) address

Tags: java, android, android-location, geocoder

I am developing an android app and I am trying to check if the user's current location is the same with one of some addresses that I hold in a csv.

For example:
An address from the csv is a String like "Via dei Monti Tiburtini 385, Roma 00157 "

At first I have get the fully current location by the following code

```
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, locale);

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```

I thought to make just check if the Strings are equals but ofcourse this is not a right solution because the location addresses can differ in the way that been written.

**For example:**
csv file -> "Via dei Monti Tiburtini 385, Roma 00157 "

user's current loc -> "Via dei Monti Tiburtini 385, Roma 00157, ITALY "

***Note**: My addresses are not in english characters (both user's current loc and csv loc) but for now I would like to find a solution at least for english*

I am trying to find something on the web but I am not able to find something similar to that.
I would appreciate any help, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Checking if GPS coordinates are equal might be too restrictive, I agree with you. What you could do is check if they are within a certain range, maybe 0.01% margin from what's in your DB. You can test it on Google Maps and see how much you think you can tolerate based on your application.

This page has some details about the numerical values for latitude and longitude:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

From a user address perspective, in my experience with shipping applications, there is this concept of Address Standardization which tries to make the addresses conform in format so that other systems consistently find the same location.

This could help with how people enter their address for example "apartment #3" or "app #3" or "app 3", which could all result in different addresses. There are libraries for UPS and others that provide this.

https://www.ups.com/us/en/services/shipping/connectship.page

This is if you are starting from an address.

If you start from GPS location, you could use API-s available on the web, maybe Google Maps, to find the address of a specific GPS location.

https://www.google.com/maps/@44.4257258,-88.1063132

and this:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop